# How can I force Idea and Maven download all sources for my project?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

My Java project is build with Maven and written with the help of Intellij Idea. I have a lot of open-source project dependencies and I want to study them extensively to understand how they work. For this I often use a usage search in Idea, i.e. Find Usages option, which tells me where the usages of some class can be found. Also it can be Find In Path option, or some other code navigation tool.

The problem is that I am not sure all the sources are downloaded. Thats why my search may give wrong results.

A question is : how can I force Idea and Maven download all the sources for my project and make all my searches complete ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the 'Maven Projects' tab on the side of the Idea window is a toolbar button (looks like a box with a green arrow pointing down) for downloading sources and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ 2018.2.3 Ultimate Edition, click on "Maven Projects" on the right hand side of the window (vertical text alignment). Then click the third button on the left in the toolbar (arrow pointing down to a horizontal line- not green for me).

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on `pom.xml` > Maven > Generate Sources and Update Folders

Answer (score 0):

One option is to right-click the `pom.xml` file and select `Maven` -> `Download sources` in the context menu.